# extension update does not show up in joomla

Tags: extension-update

I have the update XML shown below.

The last update I published was with Joomla! 3.6, so the target platform was 3.6
I now changed it to 3.[6789] to support all versions since 3.6. But the update does not show up.

For clarification, I have the version 3.0.0 installed and try to update to 3.1.0.

I used https://docs.joomla.org/Deploying_an_Update_Server for creating the xml.

```
<updates>
    <update>
        <name>SchuWeb Sitemap</name>
        <description>SchuWeb Sitemap - Sitemap Generator for Joomla!</description>
        <element>com_schuweb_sitemap</element>
        <type>package</type>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <infourl title="SchuWeb Sitemap 3.1.0">https://extensions.schultschik.com/products/schuweb-sitemap/schuweb-sitemap-3-1-0</infourl>
        <downloads>
            <downloadurl type="full" format="zip">https://github.com/svanschu/SchuWeb-Sitemap/releases/download/3.1.0/pkg_schuweb_sitemap_3.1.0_20200417.zip</downloadurl>
        </downloads>
        <tags>
            <tag>stable</tag>
        </tags>
        <maintainer>Sven Schultschik</maintainer>
        <maintainerurl>http://www.schultschik.de</maintainerurl>
        <section>frs</section>
        <targetplatform name="joomla" version="3.[6789]" />
        <php_minimum>5.6</php_minimum>
    </update>
```

...

Link to the complete update xml: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/svanschu/SchuWeb-Sitemap/master/update/schuweb_sitemap.xml

What am I missing, I don't see the mistake ...

Comment: May be a silly question, but have you actually released an update...higher than v3.1.0?

Comment: @Lodder see the link of the complete xml. I have a 3.0.0 installed and want to update to 3.1.0, But 3.1.0 does not appear.

Comment: I tried accessing the URL for your download URL and got Not Found. Can you check you've got it right.

Comment: @RobbieJackson github deaktivated the release, it'S back now, but still the same behaviour

Comment: OK. Have you checked the relevant records in the extensions, update_sites and update_sites_extensions tables for your component? If you could add them to your question it might help diagnose the problem. And I presume you've no relevant record in your updates table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, it seems that a bug in the joomla updater was fixed some time ago. So the important part was the `<type>` tag.

The working XML:

```
<updates>
    <update>
        <name>SchuWeb Sitemap</name>
        <description>SchuWeb Sitemap - Sitemap Generator for Joomla!</description>
        <element>com_schuweb_sitemap</element>
        <type>component</type>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <infourl title="SchuWeb Sitemap 3.1.0">https://extensions.schultschik.com/products/schuweb-sitemap/schuweb-sitemap-3-1-0</infourl>
        <downloads>
            <downloadurl type="full" format="zip">https://github.com/svanschu/SchuWeb-Sitemap/releases/download/3.1.0/pkg_schuweb_sitemap_3.1.0_20200417.zip</downloadurl>
        </downloads>
        <tags>
            <tag>stable</tag>
        </tags>
        <maintainer>Sven Schultschik</maintainer>
        <maintainerurl>http://www.schultschik.de</maintainerurl>
        <targetplatform name="joomla" version="3.[6789]" />
        <php_minimum>5.6</php_minimum>
    </update>
    <update>
        <name>SchuWeb Sitemap</name>
        <description>SchuWeb Sitemap - Sitemap Generator for Joomla!</description>
        <element>com_schuweb_sitemap</element>
        <type>component</type>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <infourl title="SchuWeb Sitemap 3.0.0">https://extensions.schultschik.com/products/schuweb-sitemap/schuweb-sitemap-3-0-0</infourl>
        <downloads>
            <downloadurl type="full" format="zip">https://github.com/svanschu/SchuWeb-Sitemap/releases/download/3.0.0/pkg_schuweb_sitemap_3.0.0_20190412.zip</downloadurl>
        </downloads>
        <tags>
            <tag>stable</tag>
        </tags>
        <maintainer>Sven Schultschik</maintainer>
        <maintainerurl>http://www.schultschik.de</maintainerurl>
        <targetplatform name="joomla" version="3.[6789]" />
        <php_minimum>5.6</php_minimum>
    </update>
</updates>
```